# For routes over oceans, are slide rafts fitted with first-aid items, food, water, radio, etc?

Tags: emergency, ditching

Nowadays life rafts are often replaced by slide rafts, the slides having a double function: Evacuation and when detached survival. However they are packed tightly in the aircraft doors, so they probably don't contain a survival kit.

[image]
<sup>Nice illustration by [Ron Wilson](http://www.ronsillustrations.com/19-photographs/iylf71rm5zkmur53jnj60bnsse89mg)</sup>
<sup>Though it would be typical of ditching on Lake Michigan, not [in heavy sea](http://gonautical.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/980ba11dd8e8a95d34a593804a3039c3.jpg)</sup>

For routes over oceans, what is the equipment that is available aboard rafts when they are used? (first-aid items, food, water, radio, etc). Where is this equipment stored before evacuation? Who takes care of making this equipment available in each raft?

Comment: I would be surprised if food and water are supplied.  Its not expected that these become long-term life-rafts.  Rescue should typically be less than a day away.  The urgent need would be medical supplies, not food/water.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
([Source](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/pspages/eam-sk-747-4.php)) *A Boeing 747 raft survival kit.*

Typical content does [include](http://www.skygeek.com/eam-sk-747-4-kit-base-renewal-boeing-747-s3045-101.html) nonperishable food and bagged water—

Base kit:

> - Survival Manual
> - Flashlight, w/Lithium Batteries
> - Knife Assy., Utility
> - Signal Mirror Assy.
> - Sea Dye Marker
> - Raft Repair Kit
> - Whistle Assy.
> - **Water Package Assy. (4.23 fl. oz. per pack)**
> - Bailing Bucket
> - Sponge
> - Lip Balm
> - Adhesive Bandage, 1 in (16 per box)
> - Bandage Compress, 2 in (4 per box)
> - Bandage Compress, 4 in (1 per box)
> - Triangle Bandage, 40 in
> - Adhesive Tape (2 rolls per pack)

Renewal kit:

> - Sea Sickness Pill Packs (12 tablets per pack)
> - Day/Night Flare
> - Water Purification Tablets (50 tablets per bottle)
> - Antiseptic Swabs (10 swabs per box)
> - Ammonia Inhalants (10 vials per box)
> - Burn Compound (10 tubes per box)
> - Eye Dressing Packet
> - **Candy (Sucrose) Rations (10 candies per pack)**

It's the crew responsibility to gather the kits.

They're located near the exits either in closets, ceiling compartments, attendant seat stowage, or overhead bins. Exact location varies by plane and airline.

Axes, first aid kits, ropes, fire extinguishers, megaphones, etc., are also stored in the same locations mentioned above.

Comment: What about articles required by regulation to be on a raft? E.g. ELT, canopy, roars, compass... It could be good to mention regulation itself.