# What do you need to have onboard for flights with an ultralight/sport aircraft over water (Atlantic, Pacific)? Life raft possible (weight/size)?

Tags: safety, flight-planning, emergency-procedures, ultralight, oceanic

**Remark:** For us in Germany an UL is a 2 seater with 470/600kg MTOW. AFAIK those are named Light Sport Aircraft in the US/Australia. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikarus_C42

What do you use if you fly with your UL/Sports aircraft over water? As a reference I did try to find out what other pilots have used:

Some people have surrounded the world with an ultralight aircraft. A recent example here: https://flyzolo.com/ Did they have a life raft onboard? Or is an [Immersion Suit/Survival Suit](https://maritime-executive.com/corporate/immersion-suit-adds-19-hours-survival-time) sufficient? Or are there even other options?

[Life rafts](https://www.westmarine.com/life-rafts) do not seem to be to heavy, but would it possible to deploy them after ditching? Or would it just be impossible to deploy such a raft in such a case?

I have also watched a YT series "FunForLouis World Flight", they have used Immersion suits. But the flight was in a [Cessna 210](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwgyzNIw4eI) and the weight was already an issue. So I assume more restrictions with an ultralight/sports plane.

---

Edit 2022-06-22: This [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGh5MFC1jzY) shows a Cirrus with parachute ditching. Pilot manages to deploy a little raft before the plane sinks. So it seems to be feasible. Related: [Why did this Cirrus deploy the parachute while ditching over Pacific Ocean?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12048/4024)

---

Related:  But this is for "big" planes.

- [Has a life raft ever been successfully deployed on a modern commercial flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65614/4024)
- [For routes over oceans, are slide rafts fitted with first-aid items, food, water, radio, etc?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33734/4024)

Comment: Why would it be more difficult to deploy a life raft from an ultralight?

Comment: Normally you have very little storage room in an ultralight. And the raft needs to be quickly accessible from within the cabin, so the options are limited.

Comment: Your usage of "ultralight" differs from my understanding.  Perhaps you should describe what you're thinking of for an "ultralight".

Comment: The question, especially 1st pgraph, seems to be about what was done on a specific past flight.  The title seems to be more open-ended, about what is "needed" (by whose definition of "need" -- prudent avoidance of risk? meeting legal obligations?) for long-range overwater flights by "ultralights" (by whose definition of ulight? FAA definition limits empty weight to 254 pounds (115 kg) empty weight, excluding floats and safety devices, and "Shark" does not meet this definition.)  I suggest editing the title to be more harmonized to the question, about what was done on a specific past flight.

Comment: The UL point is valid. For us in Europe/Germany the term Ultralight is normally used for a 2 seater with a weight limitation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aveko_VL-3_Sprint is a UL plane for us. According to WIKIPEDIA it is Light Sport Aircraft in the US or Australia.

Thanks for point that out!

Comment: I am asking what you are using when you fly long legs over water. But if you know what others use, also fine. The best example I have found is this video with a Cessna 210 as there is one episode where they get and test the suits.

Comment: @quietflyer I could not see what Rutherford is using, obviously she als avoided water as much as possible. In the 1st picture it looks a bit like she is wearing an Immersion Suit, but pure speculation.